# Transform array of arrays via streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an array such as

```
int[][] weights = {{1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 4}, {2, 3, 3}, {3, 4, 2}, {4, 2, 1}};
```

I need to get from every array `{x, y, z}` two arrays `{x, y, z}` and `{y, x, z}`. Something like this

```
int[][] resultWeights = {{1, 3, 2}, {3, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 4}, {1, 2, 4} ...
```

How it can be done via streams?

Comment: Not sure what the first array is supposed to represent? What are the entries in the arrays? It's not an adjacency matrix, because it's 5x3 instead of 5x5 or 3x3. What exactly do you mean by "weights"? Are those arrays somehow a combination of node indices and weights? Is it `{source, target, weight}`?

Comment: Start of by doing it without stream first. Show us your attempt. Then we can easily transform that. To me it looks like you just want to insert some reversed arrays in between. Just do that. I don't see why streams would help here.

Comment: What do you mean with "weight of a graph"? Normally, you store weights in a weight-matrix, which is a square matrix. Your example is not square. Also, if you have directed weights, how would you transform them to undirected weights? Take the minimum? Maximum? means?

Comment: The main point is in array's transformation.

Comment: It got clearer after the edits, good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to get from every array `{x, y, z}` two arrays `{x, y, z}` and `{y, x, z}`.

Iterate your source and explicitly create the new entries:

```
int[][] weights = ...
// Every entry yields two
int[][] resultWeights = new int[weights.length * 2][];

// Iterate all entries
int i = 0;
for (int[] entry : weights) {
    // Copy entry
    resultWeights[i] = entry;
    i++;
    // Other version
    resultWeights[i] = new int[] { entry[1], entry[0], entry[2] };
    i++;
}
```

Note that you can do `resultWeights[i++]` instead. May be unfamiliar to some programmers though.

---

As you specifically asked for streams:

```
int[][] weights = ...
int[][] resultWeights = Arrays.stream(weights)
    .flatMap(entry -> Stream.of(entry, new int[] { entry[1], entry[0], entry[2] }))
    .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

Comment: Neat use of `int[][]::new`, (+1).

Answer (score 2):

Just `flatMap` each entry `{x, y, w}` to Stream of arrays `[{x, y, w}, {y, x, w}]`. Something like this should work:

```
Arrays.stream(weights)
  .flatMap(arr -> {
    int[] opp = new int[]{arr[1], arr[0], arr[2]};
    return Stream.of(arr, opp);
  })
  .toArray(i -> new int[i][]);
```

Full code example:

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

class SymmetrizeGraphMatrix {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] weights = {{1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 4}, {2, 3, 3}, {3, 4, 2}, {4, 2, 1}};
    int[][] result = Arrays.stream(weights)
      .flatMap(arr -> {
        int[] opp = new int[]{arr[1], arr[0], arr[2]};
        return Stream.of(arr, opp);
      })
      .toArray(i -> new int[i][]);

    for (int[] xyw : result) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xyw));
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 2]
[3, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 4]
[1, 2, 4]
[2, 3, 3]
[3, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 2]
[4, 3, 2]
[4, 2, 1]
[2, 4, 1]
```

Comment: Mind the existence of array initializers: `int[] opp = { arr[1], arr[0], arr[2] };`…

Comment: @Holger I'd like to write down a shorter solution, but then it quickly collapses into `.flatMap{a -> Stream.of(a, new int[]{a[1], a[0], a[2]})}`, which is the same as what Zabuza already has. Don't want to invoke impression as if I copy-pasted someone else's solution, so I'll leave it as a reminder for myself that one needs a `return` in the end of a lambda block in Java...

Comment: My suggestion still would be `.flatMap(arr -> { int[] opp = { arr[1], arr[0], arr[2] }; return Stream.of(arr, opp); })`. Don’t worry if it looks similar to another answer, such things happen.